# VisualStudio2005 debug into remote Linux webserver

Tags: linux, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I am debugging VisualStudio 2005 webservice client software, accessing a Linux webserver. 
VisualStudio has MSVSMON.exe for remote debugging of webserver code.
Is there an equivalent debug-monitor for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

[Yes](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-04.html), but it's not quite ready yet.  You can sign up for the preview though (you didn't specify which language, but if it is C# or VB.Net this should work).